# Os valores de opção e envio de arquivo não chegam pelo formulário

Tags: php, formulário

Consegui finalmente finalizar o formulário para envio de arquivos. O email chega a minha caixa de entrada mas sem o arquivo e sem o valor do selection, de onde o cliente marca a opção. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de onde estou errando?

```js
/* ---------------------------------------------
 Contact form
 --------------------------------------------- */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
        
        //get input field values
        var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_city = $('input[name=city]').val();
        var user_selection = $('input[name=selection]').val();
        var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
        var user_send =$('file[name=send]').val();
        
        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;
        if (user_name == "") {
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if (user_email == "") {
            $('input[name=email]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        
        if (user_message == "") {
            $('textarea[name=message]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        
        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if (proceed) {
            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'userName': user_name,
                'userEmail': user_email,
                'userCity' : user_city,
                'userSelection' : user_selection,
                'userMessage': user_message,
                'userSend' :user_send
            };
            
            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){
            
                //load json data from server and output message     
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
                }
                else {
                
                    output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                    
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val('');
                    $('#contact_form textarea').val('');
                    $('#contact_form file').val('');
                }
                
                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
            
        }
        
        return false;
    });
    
    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").keyup(function(){
        $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").css('border-color', '');
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!-- Contact Form -->                            
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">
                        <form class="form contact-form" id="contact_form">
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                      <!-- Form -->
                                    
              <!-- Nome -->
              NOME:
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-md round form-control" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
                                        </div>
                                       <!-- Email -->
                                      EMAIL:
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-md round form-control"  pattern=".{5,100}" required>
                                        </div>
                                      CIDADE:
                                        <!-- Cidade -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-md round form-control"  pattern=".{5,100}" required>
                                        </div>
               MENSAGEM:
      <div class="form-group">                                            
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-md round form-control" style="height: 118px;" ></textarea>
                                        </div></div>
     
        <h4>DEPARTAMENTO</h4>
        <select class="input-md form-control" name="selection">
          <option>ADMINISTRATIVO</option>
          <option>RECURSOS HUMANOS</option>
          <option>FINANCEIRO</option>
          <option>COMERCIAL</option>
          <option>DATA CENTER E ESTRUTURA</option>
          <option>INOVAÇÃO</option>
          <option>ESTATÍSTICA E MACHINE LEARNING</option>
          <option>SUPORTE E ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE</option>
          <option>GERENCIAMENTO E IMPLANTAÇÃO DE PROJETOS</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
      <div class="clearfix">

        <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
          <h4>ANEXE SEU CURRICULO</h4>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="send">

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Send Button -->
      <div class="align-left pt-10">
        <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Enviar Mensagem</button>
      </div>

      <div id="result">

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

                    
                    <!-- End Contact Form -->
                    
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End Contact Section -->
```

Comment: Dentro de cada option deve ter a tag `value` com o valor que será enviado pelo formulário. exemplo: `<option value="arroz">Arroz</option>`

Comment: TESTE MENSAGEM 12


>> CRISTINA FERNANDES

>> cristadesigner@gmail.com

>> SÃO PAULO

>> 

>> @ViniciusDeJesus ainda aparece vazio mesmo com o option marcado.

Comment: Cadê o código PHP que recebe os dados do formulário, e atualize as options pra ver se tem mais algum erro.